# Importing and/or using classes of an EMF modeling project in a Java Web project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, import, eclipse-emf

I have made 2 projects.

Project A: a Java Web project

Project B: an EMF Modelling Project

I want to use some java classes from EMF modelling project(project B) that create a .XMI file, in the java Web project(Project A). I have added project B in Projects A's java build path but it is still showing a problem 'Import cannot be resolved'. ( I have tried almost every solution given on StackOverFlow).

I was wondering if there is someother way of doing this if an EMF modelling project is involved?(I am using Eclipse IDE)

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

What about: build an *headless* RCP product, exposing an API to deal with the model instances. Once done, any correctly configured java project could use the API to instantiate, persist the model you've designed, etc.